# Why not to delete tho old row and insert updated row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (MySql) that some rows need to be updated when a user desires.
i know the right way is just using Sql UPDATE statement and i don't speak about 'Which is faster? Delete and insert or just update!'. but as my table update operation needs more time to write a code (cause of table's relations) why i don't delete the old row and insert updated field?

Comment: You can do that.  It requires about twice as much work, but that's fine for some applications.

Comment: Will mess up foreign key dependencies.

Comment: @jerIh i don't have foreign key sources in my table.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff why twice work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get the answer!

in a RDBMS system there are relations between records and one record might have some dependencies. in such situations you cannot delete and insert new record because foreign key constraint cause data lose. records dependent (ie user posts) to main record (ie an user record) will be deleted!

if there are situations that you don't have records dependencies (not as exceptions! but in data models nature) (like no-sql) and you have some problems in updating a record (ie file checking) you can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can **delete** and **insert**. but what keeps the record in your database if the program crash a moment before it can insert data to Database?

**Update** keeps this from happening. It keeps the data in your database and change the value that needed to be changed. Maybe it is complicated to use in your database, but you can certain that your record still safe.